# Product of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a prime number less than the product of consecutive primes, but greater than the last consecutive prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257258/is-there-a-prime-number-less-than-the-product-of-consecutive-primes-but-greater)

It's been a while since I graduated college, and I haven't used my degree since, but I started thinking about this problem this morning:

Consider a product of consecutive primes

$\Pi_{i=N}^{M}p_i = X$

Is there always a prime between $p_M$ and $X$?

I feel like there should be an elementary proof of this, but I haven't done any real math in almost 6 years now.

Comment: This is a more general version of that question. Over there, he has N = 1.

Comment: @TedDziuba This is true, although it follows from Bertrand's postulate in exactly the same way.

Comment: The text of that question differs from the formula (he says product of consecutive primes, but the example assumes the first one is $1$). I would agree that this question is better phrased, maybe the earlier one should be closed as a duplicate? Particularly if the author of the earlier question clarifies that he was allowing any initial prime as in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Cocopuffs indicated, this is true from Bertrand's postulate.

- The last prime in the product of a sequence of $M-N+1$ consecutive primes is $p_M$.
- Bertrand's postulate guarantees a prime between $p_M$ and $2 \cdot p_M$.
- $2 \cdot p_M < X$ since $2 \cdot p_M$ is clearly less than $\Pi_{i=N}^{M} p_i$ (except in pathological cases, e.g., $M = N$ or $p_N = 2$).
- Therefore, there is a prime between $p_M$ and $X$.